# How can I reuse a SHARED VARIABLE in different states of a FSM in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fsm, vivado

I wrote a FSM in VHDL and I need that each process solves logic and arithmetic expressions. I need everything to be sequential and I want yo reuse SHARED VARIABLE to get results. For example:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY test1_arith IS
GENERIC (
    ap_bit_width : positive := 4;
    ap_latency : positive := 2
);
PORT (
    I1 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0);
    I2 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0);
    I3 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0);
    O1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0);
    ap_clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ap_rst : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ap_start : IN STD_LOGIC;
    ap_done : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    ap_idle : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    ap_ready : OUT STD_LOGIC
);
END;

ARCHITECTURE test1_arith_arch OF test1_arith IS
    ATTRIBUTE CORE_GENERATION_INFO : STRING;
    ATTRIBUTE CORE_GENERATION_INFO OF test1_arith_arch : ARCHITECTURE IS "Test,VHDLbyMOEA,{HLS_SYN_LAT=2}";
    CONSTANT ap_const_logic_1 : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    CONSTANT ap_const_logic_0 : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    TYPE state IS (state_1,state_2,state_3);
    SIGNAL state_present: state;
    SIGNAL state_future: state; 
    SIGNAL Flag: Integer:=0;
     --Signal RF : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR_array;
    FUNCTION ALU ( Op: IN integer range 0 TO 23;
     A, B: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0) )
    RETURN std_logic_vector is variable Result : std_logic_vector(ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0);        

    variable A_int: Integer:=0;
    variable B_int: Integer:=0;
    variable Result_int: Integer:=0;
    begin
    A_int := to_integer(unsigned(A));
    B_int := to_integer(unsigned(B));
    With Op Select Result_int:=
        to_integer(unsigned(NOT A)) When 0,
        to_integer(unsigned(A AND B)) When 1,
        to_integer(unsigned(A OR B)) When 2,
        to_integer(unsigned(A NAND B)) When 3,
        to_integer(unsigned(A NOR B)) When 4,
        to_integer(unsigned(A XOR B)) When 5,
        to_integer(unsigned(A XNOR B)) When 6,
        (A_int + B_int) When 7,
        (A_int - B_int) When 8,
        (A_int * B_int) When 9,
        (A_int / B_int) When 10,
        ABS(A_int) When 11,
        (A_int ** B_int) When 12,
        (A_int MOD B_int) When 13,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) & unsigned(B)) When 14,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) SLL B_int) When 15,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) SRL B_int) When 16,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) SLA B_int) When 17,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) SRA B_int) When 18,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) ROL B_int) When 19,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) ROR B_int) When 20,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) & unsigned(B)) When 21,
        to_integer(unsigned(A) & unsigned(B)) When 22,
                 0   When others;
    return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED (Result_int, (ap_bit_width)));
    END FUNCTION;

    SHARED VARIABLE R1:std_logic_vector(ap_bit_width - 1 downto 0);    


    BEGIN

    OP_FSM : PROCESS (state_present)

     BEGIN 
    CASE state_present IS

    WHEN state_1=> 
    R1 := ALU(Op => 7 ,A => I1,B => I2);
    Flag<=1;
    IF (Flag=1) THEN
    state_future <= state_2;
    END IF;

    WHEN state_2=> 
    R1:= ALU(Op => 7 ,A => R1, B => I3);
    Flag<=2;
    IF (Flag=2) THEN
    state_future <= state_3;
    END IF;

    WHEN state_3=> 
    O1<= ALU(Op => 7 ,A => R1,B => "0001");
    Flag<=3;
    IF (Flag=3) THEN
    state_future <= state_1;
    END IF;
    END CASE;
    END PROCESS OP_FSM;

    CLK_FSM : PROCESS (ap_clk)
    BEGIN
    IF (ap_clk = '1' AND ap_clk'EVENT) THEN
    state_present <= state_future;
    END IF;
    END PROCESS CLK_FSM;

END test1_arith_arch;
```

In this case, I want to reuse R1 and it works well in Simulation with Xilinx Vivado:

[In simulation it works: 1 + 4 + 0 + 1 = 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnDvA.png)

But I need that the FSM works in simulation and implementation with a real FPGA. Unfortunately, in the Basys 3 FPGA Artix-7 I don't get the correct results:

[Several examples: Inputs and Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cle3k.png)

In this figure, I show the Case 10 in a FPGA, it should get 6 (1+4+0+1) as result, but it gets 14 instead:
[Case 10 in Basys 3 Artix-7 FPGA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RCkv.jpg)

Any help will be very grateful.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You really want to make everything sequential ?

We need more information about the outputs you get. It is impossible to guess the problem without your logs and code.

Comment: Thank you Ayoub Bargach, I improved my explanation about the problem. Please, tell me I you need more information to identify my error.

Comment: If as I think you want to have several computations being processed at the same time (a standard pipeline), you'd better use signals and put them in registers (flip flops). And at least you should have one separate variable (A, B...) per stage of the pipeline, and propagate the values correctly from stage to stage...

Comment: If I use the SIGNAL instead SHARED VARIABLE I got the same incorrect results. Exist any way to reuse registers for this FSM?

Comment: Anyway, Why it work in simulation and not in a real FPGA?